# Conexão Python e pymysql

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou criando um sistema de login e registros de usuários. Criei um model para fazer a inserção e no controller, valido as informações e passo para o model gravar, contudo, meu model não está funcionando.

Aqui é a conexão com o banco

```
def conexao():
    import pymysql.cursors

    config = {
        'user': 'root',
        'password': 'admin',
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'database': 'megasena'
    }

    try:
        conection = pymysql.connect(**config)
        return conection
    except pymysql.InternalError as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print('Dados de acessso a Database invalidos!')
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print('Database nao existe!')
        else:
            print(err)
```

No model, eu faço a importação da conexão

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/felipe/Documents/Projetos/MegaSena/conection')
from conn import conexao

class User():

    def insere(self):
        t = conexao()
        cursor = t.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, senha, username) VALUES(
                       "Felipe Paz",
                       "xxfelipepaz@gmail.com",
                       "admin",
                       "felipepaz"
        )""")
```

Neste caso, eu estou jogando as informações direto no model para testar já que estas informações virão do controller. Mas mesmo assim, não consigo salvar essas informações no bd. Alguém saberia me dizer onde está o erro?

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro? Por quê dá *import* em `pymysql.cursors` ao invés de apenas `pymysql`?

Comment: Não da mensagem de erro. Coloquei um print no try para ver se conecta e try é executado. Coloquei cursors pq eu vi num tutorial, como dito anteriormente, sou novato no python.

Comment: Os dados do tipo caractere precisam estar entre aspas simples e não duplas.

Comment: @Pagotti: A linguagem não faz distinção entre aspas simples e aspas duplas.

Comment: @jsbueno Você se refere ao Python ou ao SQL?

Comment: no Python. - nem tinha visto o comando de sql dele. Não vai executar por que esa importando o módulo errado, como o Andersn apontou. De qualquer forma, sem mensagem de erro é bem dificil responder.

Answer (score 0):

Da um t.commit() após o cursor.execute()

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/felipe/Documents/Projetos/MegaSena/conection')
from conn import conexao

class User():

    def insere(self):
        t = conexao()
        cursor = t.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, senha, username) VALUES(
                       "Felipe Paz",
                       "xxfelipepaz@gmail.com",
                       "admin",
                       "felipepaz"
        )""")
        t.commit()
```